# How can I polish shoes without getting shoe polish on my hands?

Tags: shoes

When I polish shoes, I always get shoe polish on my hands. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What did you try to avoid getting polish on your hands? Have you had this problem with other activities and what did you do then?

Answer (score 3):

Wear gloves.  Cheap rubber gloves or less cheap reusable ones.

Comment: Or for a cheaper solution put plastic bags you were about to throw away anyway over both of your hands.

Answer (score 2):

I use a rag to hold the thing I'm brushing/polishing with - which can be another rag or a brush.

Personally I prefer not to use gloves, from environmental aspects. And I was always possible to keep my hands clean.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bigger rag or multiple rags so that you can have more clean area to hold onto besides the part with shoe polish on it. Also try using smaller amounts of polish at a time.